# Remove last word after comma in a string jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to remove last word after comma in a string.

For example, i have string like below

```
var text = "abc, def, gh";
```

I want to remove `gh` in that string

I have tried like below

```
var text = "abc, def, gh";
var result = text.split(",");
var get = result.substring(-1, result.length);
alert(get);
```

But im getting error

> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Please help me.

Comment: `var text = abc, def, gh;` it is not correct  string,  so it should be `var text = "abc, def, gh";`

Comment: Missing the double quotes around your string??

Comment: Sorry, now edited my question

Comment: split returns a array, use slice on result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this using array operations:

```js
var text = "abc, def, gh";
//create the array 
var resArray = text.split(",");
//remove last element from array
var poppedItem = resArray.pop();
//change the final array back to string
var result = resArray.toString();
console.log(result);
```

Or you can do it by string operations:

```js
var text = "abc, def, gh";
//find the last index of comma
var lastCommaIndex = text.lastIndexOf(",");
//take the substring of the original string
var result = text.substr(0,lastCommaIndex);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: What if i dont want to remove last comma, i just want to remove the last word..how can i achieve this

Comment: You can do that with ```var result = text.substr(0,lastCommaIndex+1)```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var text = "abc, def, gh";
var str=text.replace(/(.*),.*/, "$1");
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var str = "abc, def, gh";

var result = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(","));

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split return an array, You should slice/pop it cause sub-string is a poperty of a string, or you can use regex as other mentions.

```
var text = "abc, def, gh";
var result = text.split(",");
var get = result.slice(0, result.length-1);
// or var get = result.pop();
alert(get);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I use `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()` methods. `substring()` is used to collect the string from Oth index to last empty space.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var str = "abc, def, gh";
            var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
            str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
            document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = str;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <h1>the value of string is now:  <span id="myText"></span></h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using a regex without a capture group:

```js
var text = "abc, def, gh";
text = text.replace(/(?=,[^,]*$).*/, "");
console.log(text);
```

This regex strategically removes just the final word in the CSV list.

Here is a variation of the above which uses a capture group:

```
text = text.replace(/(.*),.*/, "$1");
console.log(text);
```